# Why won't my list of data show in my XML?

Tags: xslt

So there's supposed to be employee data in list form on the website, but nothing pops up after the 'Employee Report'. I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I looked through most of the book, and can't seem to see what the problem is. Can someone help?

This is my XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML, 3rd Edition
   Tutorial 7
   Case Problem 1

   Employee List
   Author: 
   Date:   4/6/2020

   Filename:         hbemployees.xml
   Supporting Files: hbemployees.xsl

-->

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="hbemployees.xsl" ?>

<employees xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <employee empID="4">
      <name>Heffner, Marian</name>
      <position>Chief Operating Officer</position>
      <phone>x10962</phone>
      <email>mheffner50@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>262000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="192">
      <name>Murff, Nicolle</name>
      <position>Mgr Software Client Supp</position>
      <phone>x32524</phone>
      <email>nmurff63@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Sales</department>
      <salary>137000</salary>
      <gender>female</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="295">
      <name>Vecchio, Art</name>
      <position>Line Worker</position>
      <phone>x12125</phone>
      <email>avecchio55@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Management</department>
      <salary>83000</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Part Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
   <employee empID="294">
      <name>Lewis, Richard</name>
      <position>Met Read/Coll</position>
      <phone>x22131</phone>
      <email>rlewis19@example.com/harrisbarnes</email>
      <department>Production</department>
      <salary>74500</salary>
      <gender>male</gender>
      <maritalStatus>married</maritalStatus>
      <workStatus>Full Time</workStatus>
   </employee>
```

This is my XSL:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
   New Perspectives on XML, 3rd Edition
   Tutorial 7
   Case Problem 1

   Harris and Barnes Style Sheet
   Author: 
   Date:   4/6/2020

   Filename:         hbemployees.xsl
   Supporting Files: 
-->


<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="departments" match="employee" use="department" />


   <xsl:output method="html"
      doctype-system="about:legacy-compat"
      encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" />


   <xsl:template match="/">
      <html>
         <head>
            <title>Employee Report</title>
            <link href="hbstyles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
         </head>

         <body>
            <div id="wrap">
               <header>
                  <img src="hblogo.png" alt="Harris and Barnes" />
               </header>

               <h1>Employee Report</h1>
               <xsl:for-each select="//employeee[generate-id()=generate-id(key('departments', department)[1])]">
                   <xsl:sort select="department" />
                   <table class="employeeList">
                       <caption><xsl:value-of select="department" /></caption>
                       <thead>
                           <tr>
                               <th>Name</th>
                               <th>Position</th>
                               <th>Salary</th>
                               <th>Phone</th>
                               <th>Gender</th>
                               <th>Marital Status</th>
                               <th>Work Status</th>
                           </tr>
                       </thead>
                       <tbody>
                           <xsl:apply-templates select="key('departments', department)">
                               <xsl:sort select="salary" order="descending" />
                           </xsl:apply-templates>
                       </tbody>
                   </table>
               </xsl:for-each>
             </div>
         </body>

      </html>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="employees/employee">
       <tr>
           <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="name"/>
           </td>
           <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="position"/>
           </td>
           <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="format-number(salary,'$#,##0')"/>
           </td>
           <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="phone"/>
           </td>
           <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="gender"/>
           </td>
           <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="maritalStatus"/>
           </td>
           <td>
               <xsl:value-of select="workStatus"/>
           </td>
       </tr>
   </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

What am I doing wrong? It doesn't even show me an error, it just won't show up.

Answer (score 0):

Your input has two XML declarations and the closing tag for `employees` is missing.

In your stylesheet, you have `employeee` instead of `employee` in:

```
           <xsl:for-each select="//employeee[generate-id()=generate-id(key('departments', department)[1])]">
```

Comment: ... 
I hate mistakes like that. Thank you so much.